# Elasticsearch Kibana EQL query to match events containing a string in field value

Tags: string, elasticsearch, kibana, eql

In ElasticSearch Kibana i need to query all the events that include the string "My text" in a certain field value.

I need to use **basic EQL syntax** (not the API syntax), since i'm creating a new security rule in the elastic dashboard.

Here's what i tried:

```
any where myField like "My text"
```

which produced the following error:

```
> cannot operate on field of data type [text]: No keyword/multi-field
> defined exact matches for [myField]; define one or use MATCH/QUERY
> instead
```

same result with the EQL:

```
any where myField : "My text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your synthax is correct. But the like operator only works with the keyword field type, as you can see in this link: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-run-sql-query-on-multi-fields-using-elastic-search-v-7-3/222321

Try to change the type of your field.

Comment: unfortunately i can't change it. is there any other option to match a string within a text type field?

Comment: you can use the other operators, check this doc, maybe it will help you

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/eql-syntax.html